# Return the number of all unique case-insensitive characters

Tags: php, string

I am trying create a function which returns the number of all unique case-insensitive
characters that occur `>= $n` times in a given string.

For example:

```
function getNumOfUniqueCharacters($str, $n) {
    // ...
}
getNumOfUniqueCharacters('A1B2C3', 2); // 0
getNumOfUniqueCharacters('A1a1C1', 2); 
// 2, because A and 1 both occur 2 or more times.
getNumOfUniqueCharacters('Alabama', 3); // 1
```

I did this:

```
function getNumOfUniqueCharacters($text)
{
    $ret = 0;
    $a = [];
    $t = str_split(strtolower($text));
    $l = count($t);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++) {
        $c = $t[$i];
        if (array_key_exists($c, $t)) {
            if ($t[$c] === 1)
                $ret += 1;
            $t[$c] += 1;
        } else {
            $t[$c] = 1;
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

But it does not work so good, I need to add second argument `$n`.
How to add it correctly?

Comment: How about using `array_count_values()`?

Comment: I posted my answer below which is almost identical to @Răzvan's but I want to point out that your function name is misleading as well, I would rename it to i.e. `countDuplicatedChars` or something to that effect

Comment: What @Prof said. The name of your function is quite misleading, because "get number of unique characters", at least for me, would mean to count how many characters are there that are NOT repeating at all. `countDuplicatedChars` like @Prof suggested is a great idea.

Comment: @RoboRobok you legend, I updated my answer using your suggestion and its MUCH cleaner, a massive +1 from me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I got your question right.
Here's my idea for this code:

```
<?php

$string = "A1B2C1A2b2b4b5";

function getNumOfUniqueCharacters($string, $n)
{
    $occurrenceArray = array();
    $text = str_split(strtolower($string));

    //put each character in a keyValue array and count them
    foreach($text as $character){
        if(!array_key_exists($character, $occurrenceArray)) $occurrenceArray[$character] = 1;
        else $occurrenceArray[$character]++;
    }

    //loop through keyValue array and remove everything that has value < $n
    foreach($occurrenceArray as $key => $value)
    {
        if($value < $n) unset($occurrenceArray[$key]);
    }

    //return array
    return $occurrenceArray;
}

print_r(getNumOfUniqueCharacters($string, 2));
```

This code right here will print the following:

```
Array ( 
   [a] => 2 
   [1] => 2 
   [b] => 4 
   [2] => 3 )
```

**Edit:** If you need the count of how many characters repeat more than $n, you can simply replace the return with `return count($occurrenceArray);`

Comment: Well, touché :) we have roughly the same answers and roughly the same time XD (I didnt see your answer until I posted mine haha)

Comment: @Prof haha, indeed! I totally forgot about the array_filter in PHP. Thanks for reminding me about that, haha!

Answer (score 1):

This task is pretty easy, if you use array functions of PHP:

```
function getNumOfUniqueCharacters(string $string = '', int $n = 1): int {
    // Split the string by character and count the occurences of all values
    $counted = array_count_values(mb_str_split(mb_strtolower($str)));
    // Discard everything, that is does not match the $n parameter
    $counted = array_filter($counted, function($a) use($n) {
        return $a >= $n;
    });
    // Return the length of the remaining array
    return count($counted);
}
```

Also note, that you may use mb_* functions, so your code will work with multibyte characters.

Comment: Nice work, I like the multi-byte consideration

Answer (score 0):

I have written you a function with a lot of comments to explain the thought process,

```
function getNumOfUniqueCharacters($string, $n = null) {

  // Map all case-insensitive characters to an array
  $map = str_split(strtolower($string), 1);

  // Character registry
  $reg = array_count_values($map);

  // Filter out single occurances
  $reg = array_filter($reg, function($v){return $v > 1;});

  // Filter out less than $n occurances (if $n is not null)
  if (null !== $n) {
    $reg = array_filter($reg, function($v)use($n){return $v >= $n;});
  }

  // Return the number duplicate occurances (or more than n occurances)
  return count($reg);

}
```

Usage:

```
echo getNumOfUniqueCharacters('A1B2C3', 2) . PHP_EOL;
echo getNumOfUniqueCharacters('A1a1C1', 2) . PHP_EOL;
echo getNumOfUniqueCharacters('Alabama', 3) . PHP_EOL;
echo getNumOfUniqueCharacters('Mississippi') . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
0
2
1
3
```